# Keep zoom when updating pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I update a live plot in a pyplot window with something like this:

```
while True:
    plt.plot(x,y)
    plt.pause(0.005)
    plt.clf()
```

However, when I zoom and/or pan in the pyplot window, the view resets on every `plt.clf()`.

Is there a way to keep the zoom? Maybe saving and restoring the view state somehow? Maybe not using `plt.clf()`, which apparently deletes line handles, but instead update the data of my lines and redraw?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update the data of the line instead of clearing everything.

```
line, = plt.plot([],[])
for i in range(100):
    line.set_data(x,y)
    plt.draw()
    plt.pause(0.0001)
```